# How to use multiple template URL in one Component in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I have two flows but different templates to be shown.
I have Search.component.html and SearchAdvanced.component.html.
I want to flip Template Url based on the input value.
search [type]="basic" should give Search.component.html.
search [type]="advanced"should give SearchAdvanced.component.html.

Can I know how to achieve scenario?

Comment: Creating 2 different components and using `*ngIf` is the simplest solution here, not sure why you want to be unnecessarily complicated

Comment: in angular 1.6.8 controller is same for both templates.

Comment: is it angular or angularjs??

Comment: If is Angular, (not Angular Js) you can also have a "base component" (with all the common functions) and two different component that extends this "base component"